# Convert JsonString int values to string in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, object, mapper

```
{
 "value" : 1234,
 "value2" : 123456
}
```

convert it to

```
{
 "value" : "123456",
 "value2" : "123456"
}
```

I am using ObjectMapper class , my aim is to parseJSON to Mapper class .
But now the response has changed due to certain need. Initially all the values  were in string but now values are in other types.
So is it better to make changes in whole application or  there is some way that i could convert all the values to string type in a complex json.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Transform`:

```
/// A transform which converts JSON to `String`.
///
/// - warning: It doesn't gaurantee the original type when convert `String` to JSON.
struct StringTransform: TransformType {

  func transformFromJSON(_ value: Any?) -> String? {
    return value.flatMap(String.init(describing:))
  }

  func transformToJSON(_ value: String?) -> Any? {
    return value
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
  stringValue <- (map["value2"], StringTransform())
}
```

Comment: Thats what i was looking for .Thanks a lot , you saved me lot of time.